Apply class to headings in quarto revealjs
I am using Quarto to create slides with reveal.js. When a title slide is long, I want it to be in a smaller font size, plus other changes. I thought of creating a class to modify the heading when it was too long, but I am not able to apply the class. This what I have in my custom.css file:
.longtitle{
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

This is my qmd code:
---
title: test
format: revealjs
self-contained: true
css: custom.css
---

## Short title

- Item

## Very very long title that goes in two lines

- Item

<h2 class="longtitle">Try to apply the "longtitle" class</h2>

- Not working


This is because your css gets overwritten by the .reveal h2 styles. Instead, a possibility is to use a span. The css can stay as it is and we use
## [Try to apply the "longtitle" class]{.longtitle}

what defines a span which has the longtitle class, where the span is located inside an h2, so that it is in particular inside a suitable header.
custom.css
.longtitle {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

index.qmd
---
title: test
format: revealjs
self-contained: true
css: custom.css
---

## Short title

- Item

## Very very long title that goes in two lines

- Item

## [Try to apply the "longtitle" class]{.longtitle}

- Working



Fantastic. Is there a way to apply the class while using markdown notation (## Title)?

Maybe using a span. Use e.g. ## [Try to apply the "longtitle" class]{.longtitle} and the css from your OP.

I just noticed a problem in your solution: when I try to move the title in a new slide using the --- separator, the class is not applied, so I cannot accept your solution.
---
title: test
format: revealjs
self-contained: true
css: custom.css
---

## Short title

- Item

## Very very long title that goes in two lines

- Item

---

<h2 class="longtitle">Try to apply the "longtitle" class</h2>

- Not working


This is not a problem with my solution. You just can't use --- here, then you need an approach e.g. as given in my earlier comment. "When I try to move the title in a new slide using the --- separator" - Read the docs: "... you can also delineate slides using horizontal rules (for example, if you have a slide without a title)".

I see, so I'm back at square one: how can I apply a class to the title of  slide?

Is the span approach from my first comment not suitable? It defines a title on a new slide which has the desired class.

I tried it but it applied the class to the slide body as well because I forgot the square brackets! After adding the brackets it works, so if you want to update your anwer I'm going to accept it. Thank you for your support!
